# Comprobar si Arduino está conectado via USB con Python

Tags: python, arduino, serialport, usb, pyserial

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que involucra Arduino y, si bien manejo C++ y Java, soy nuevo en la programación con Python en cuanto a la manipulación del módulo 'serial'.

Una parte del programa en Python debe ejecutarse constantemente mientras la PC esté encendida con el programa corriendo, así que está dentro de un loop 'while' de la siguiente forma:

```py
while True:
      #Accion a ejecutar
```

La tarea se realiza correctamente, pero es requisito que antes de volver a ejecutar el loop 'while' haya una comprobación de conexión: Python debe chequear si Arduino sigue conectado a la PC para poder comunicarse con él. Represento en Python a Arduino de la forma:

```py
device = serial.Serial("COM5",9600)
```

Intenté utilizar el método 'isOpen()' para chequear cada vez que se ejecute el loop 'while' si Arduino sigue conectado, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```py
#Líneas de código anteriores al bloque con el problema...

device = serial.Serial("COM5",9600)

while True:
   if not device.isOpen()
      print("FATAL COMMUNICATION ERROR")
      time.sleep(3)
      exit(1)

   #Resto del programa...

   time.sleep(120)

   #Fin del loop 'while'.
```

Por alguna razón, si Arduino está conectado y lo desconecto en medio de la ejecución del programa, cada vez que se corre nuevamente el loop 'while', el programa nunca detecta que Arduino se ha desenchufado. Simplemente vuelve a correr todo lo que haya en el loop 'while' y cuando llega a la parte de enviar/recibir datos de Arduino, lanza un error y se cierra (lógicamente, porque Arduino está desconectado).
Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente forma:

```py
#Líneas de código anteriores al bloque con el problema...

device = serial.Serial("COM5",9600)

while True:
    device.close()

    try:
        device = serial.Serial("COM5",9600)
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        print("FATAL COMMUNICATION ERROR")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit(1)

   #Resto del programa...

   time.sleep(120)

   #Fin del loop 'while'.
```

En palabras: cada vez que se corre el loop 'while', se cierra el puerto donde está conectado Arduino y se reintenta conectar con el mismo. Si es posible, significa que nunca fue desconectado, por lo que el programa sigue corriendo normalmente. De lo contrario, se le avisa al usuario que hubo un error de comunicación, y se cierra el programa para evitar problemas.

¿No es acaso poco eficiente el hecho de comprobar la conexión usando device.close() y reintentando conectarse? ¿Puede esto dañar el puerto o el dispositivo conectado? ¿Por qué puede ser que no me esté funcionando utilizar el método 'isOpen()'? ¿Hay alguna forma más sencilla de lograr lo que quiero?

Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Si no me equivoco la única forma efectiva de saber si el dispositivo sigue físicamente conectado al otro lado es tratar de enviar un mensaje y ver si responde. Aún con el dispositivo desconectado la conexión serie puede seguir existiendo y el puerto abierto, que es lo que comprueba el método `is_open` (`isOpen` está marcado como "deprecated" por cierto desde la versíon 3.x)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, voy a tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: Verifica esta solución para un problema similar en SO. Intentaron un approach con list_ports https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450813/11649862

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡me ha servido bastante!